# 'Algo' object has no attribute 'audio'

Tags: python, audio

I'm getting two errors, the ''Algo' object has no attribute 'audio'' and name 'logNorm' is not defined

Am I perhaps forgetting to load some libraries?

My code is on Google [collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19m-PDSqyCCQSAwjxNMGibOOmLG5JbrIZ).

The code in question is:

> from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
>   import essentia
>
> mfccs = []
>   melbands = []
>   melbands_log = []
>
> for frame in FrameGenerator(audio, frameSize=1024, hopSize=512, startFromZero=True):
>       mfcc_bands, mfcc_coeffs = mfcc(spectrum(w(frame)))
>       mfccs.append(mfcc_coeffs)
>       melbands.append(mfcc_bands)
>       melbands_log.append(logNorm(mfcc_bands))
>   mfccs = essentia.array(mfccs).T
>   melbands = essentia.array(melbands).T
>   melbands_log = essentia.array(melbands_log).T
>
> imshow(melbands[:,:], aspect = 'auto', origin='lower', interpolation='none')
>   plt.title("Mel band spectral energies in frames")
>   show()
>
> imshow(melbands_log[:,:], aspect = 'auto', origin='lower', interpolation='none')
>   plt.title("Log-normalized mel band spectral energies in frames")
>   show()
>
> imshow(mfccs[1:,:], aspect='auto', origin='lower', interpolation='none')
>   plt.title("MFCCs in frames")
>   show()
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        10     mfccs.append(mfcc_coeffs)
>        11     melbands.append(mfcc_bands)
>   ---> 12     melbands_log.append(logNorm(mfcc_bands))
>        13 
>        14 # transpose to have it in a better shape
>
> NameError: name 'logNorm' is not defined

And:

> from pylab import *
>   from essentia.streaming import *
>   loader = ess.MonoLoader(filename=file)
>   framecutter = ess.FrameCutter(frameSize=4096, hopSize=2048)
>   windowing = ess.Windowing(type='blackmanharris62')
>   spectrum = ess.Spectrum()
>   spectralpeaks = ess.SpectralPeaks(orderBy='magnitude',
>                                     magnitudeThreshold=0.00001,
>                                     minFrequency=20,
>                                     maxFrequency=3500,
>                                     maxPeaks=60)
>
> hpcp = ess.HPCP()
>   hpcp_key = ess.HPCP(size=36, # we will need higher resolution for Key estimation
>                       referenceFrequency=440, # assume tuning frequency is 44100.
>                       bandPreset=False,
>                       minFrequency=20,
>                       maxFrequency=3500,
>                       weightType='cosine',
>                       nonLinear=False,
>                       windowSize=1.)
>
> key = ess.Key(profileType='edma', # Use profile for electronic music
>                 numHarmonics=4,
>                 pcpSize=36,
>                 slope=0.6,
>                 usePolyphony=True,
>                 useThreeChords=True)
>   pool = essentia.Pool()
>   loader.audio >> framecutter.signal
>   framecutter.frame >> windowing.frame >> spectrum.frame
>   spectrum.spectrum >> spectralpeaks.spectrum
>   spectralpeaks.magnitudes >> hpcp.magnitudes
>   spectralpeaks.frequencies >> hpcp.frequencies
>   spectralpeaks.magnitudes >> hpcp_key.magnitudes
>   spectralpeaks.frequencies >> hpcp_key.frequencies
>   hpcp_key.hpcp >> key.pcp
>   hpcp.hpcp >> (pool, 'tonal.hpcp')
>   key.key >> (pool, 'tonal.key_key')
>   key.scale >> (pool, 'tonal.key_scale')
>   key.strength >> (pool, 'tonal.key_strength')
>   essentia.run(loader)
>
> imshow(pool['tonal.hpcp'].T, aspect='auto', origin='lower', interpolation='none')
>   plt.title("HPCPs in frames (the 0-th HPCP coefficient corresponds to A)")
>   show()
>
> print("Estimated key and scale:", pool['tonal.key_key'] + " " + pool['tonal.key_scale'])
>
> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        37 
>        38 # Connect streaming algorithms
>   ---> 39 loader.audio >> framecutter.signal
>        40 framecutter.frame >> windowing.frame >> spectrum.frame
>        41 spectrum.spectrum >> spectralpeaks.spectrum
>
> AttributeError: 'Algo' object has no attribute 'audio'

It worked earlier, I think because I ran the notebook in a different order. Somehow it doesn't work anymore now... Any thoughts? It's basically the tutorial code...